# Boolean Algebra Expression Simplification with large number of variables

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

So, I'm aware of both Karnaugh maps and Quine McCluskey, but both of those seem to require a truth table. That seems fine for say 32 bits, but even with 32 bits, that means you have 4 billion entries in your truth table.

What if you had (say) a thousand bits as input, and you had some giant formula for the outputs, but obviously enumerating them all that way would be infeasible.. (2^1024 and all that.)

Is there a way of taking an expression (say an expression like

a and b and not c and (b or c) and (not d) ... and returning a simplified expression? One that could accomodate something like hundreds or thousands of variables?

Thanks..

Comment: Some libraries, e.g. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hatt can do that for you. What are you asking for exactly? For a library written in a particular language?

Comment: @jubobs A library is fine... Tho, I'd prefer an algorithm that I could implement.. But, I'll look at the library! Thanks!

Comment: You could transform your expression into an [AND-Inverter-Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And-inverter_graph) and use local transforms to simplify it. [ABC](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~alanmi/abc/abc.htm) is a suitable tool. [Yosys](http://www.clifford.at/yosys) could be helpful as well. Perhaps, common sub-expressions can be removed using structural hashing.